# Why does a syntax error happen in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I am using a stored procedure, but it shows an error.

Paste other code from website works.

But I have no idea what's wrong with my code - please give me advice.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
> BEGIN
> insert into posts(name, message, path) values (x, y, z);
> END' at line 1

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_post (IN x Varchar(20), IN y TEXT, IN z TEXT);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO posts (name, message, path) 
    VALUES (x, y, z);
END //
```

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong but, check if the stored procedure needs ";" at the end of definition here `insert_post(IN x Varchar(20), IN y TEXT, IN z TEXT);`. I don't think it'll have a semicolon there

Comment: Thanks! work it! by         create procedure insert_post(IN x varchar(20), IN y text, IN z text)
    -> begin
    -> insert into posts (name, message, path) values(x, y, z);
    -> end
    -> //